# Bold plotly (R) pie chart labels

Tags: r, label, r-plotly

I am struggling to find a method that will bold my pie chart labels in plotly. Does anyone know how to bold the labels of a plotly pie chart? Here is my code:

```
t <- list(
family = "Ariel",
size = 15,
color = 'black')

fig <-plot_ly()
#####Fall/Winter Concentration
fig <-fig%>% add_pie(concWDper, 
                 labels = concWDper$Compounds, 
                 values = concWDper$Concentration, 
                 type = 'pie',
                 sort = FALSE,
                 textinfo = '', 
                 textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(colors = c("#9E0142", "#D53E4F", 
                "#F46D43","#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#FFFFBF", "#E6F598", 
                "#ABDDA4", "#66C2A5", "#3288BD", "#5E4FA2")),
                 domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0.75, 1)))
#####Spring/Summer Concentration
fig <-fig%>% add_pie(concSPDper, labels = concSPDper$Compounds, 
                 values = concSPDper$Concentration, type = 'pie',sort = FALSE,
                 textinfo = '', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(colors = c("#9E0142", "#D53E4F", "#F46D43", 
      "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#FFFFBF", "#E6F598", "#ABDDA4", "#66C2A5", "#3288BD", "#5E4FA2")),
                 domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0.75, 1)))

fig <-fig %>%layout(font=t,showlegend = T,
          grid=list(rows=3, columns=2),
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

fig
```

Here is some example data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yarGI5ee5ST_uzeQI-Xa2lk681d24vbIurUl6Rj58YY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bold labels could be achieved via the attribute `texttemplate` like so:

`texttemplate = '<b>%{label}</br></br>%{percent}</b>'`

To adjust the margins make use of layout attribute `margin`, e.g.

```
margin = list(b = 200, l = 100)
```

Using the example data from [here](https://plotly.com/r/pie-charts/):

```
library(plotly)
USPersonalExpenditure <- data.frame("Categorie"=rownames(USPersonalExpenditure), USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- USPersonalExpenditure[,c('Categorie', 'X1960')]

p <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Categorie, values = ~X1960, type = 'pie',sort = FALSE,
             textinfo = 'label+percent', 
             texttemplate = '<b>%{label}</br></br>%{percent}</b>', 
             textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
             marker = list(colors = c("#9E0142", "#D53E4F", "#F46D43", "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", 
                                      "#FFFFBF","#E6F598", "#ABDDA4", "#66C2A5", "#3288BD", "#5E4FA2")))

t <- list(
  family = "Times New Roman",
  size = 15,
  color = 'black')

p %>% layout(font=t, margin = list(b = 200, l = 100))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Now with your data

```
concWDper <- read.table(text = "Concentration   Compounds
           42   α-pinene
           10   β-pinene
           5    β-phellandrene
           13   camphene
           12   limonene
           3    tricyclene
           2    fenchene
           2    thujene
           7    cymene
           4    sabinene
           1    myrcene", header = TRUE)

t <- list(
  family = "Ariel",
  size = 15,
  color = 'black')

library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly()
#####Fall/Winter Concentration
fig <-fig%>% add_pie(concWDper,
                     labels = concWDper$Compounds, 
                     values = concWDper$Concentration, 
                     type = 'pie',
                     sort = FALSE,
                     textinfo = '', 
                     texttemplate = '<b>%{percent}</b>',
                     textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                     marker = list(colors = c("#9E0142", "#D53E4F", 
                                              "#F46D43","#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#FFFFBF", "#E6F598", 
                                              "#ABDDA4", "#66C2A5", "#3288BD", "#5E4FA2")),
                     domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0.75, 1)))

fig <-fig%>% add_pie(data = concWDper, 
                     labels = concWDper$Compounds, 
                     values = concWDper$Concentration, type = 'pie',sort = FALSE,
                     textinfo = '', 
                     texttemplate = '<b>%{percent}</b>',
                     textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                     marker = list(colors = c("#9E0142", "#D53E4F", "#F46D43", 
                                              "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#FFFFBF", "#E6F598", "#ABDDA4", "#66C2A5", "#3288BD", "#5E4FA2")),
                     domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0.75, 1)))

fig <-fig %>%layout(font=t,showlegend = T,
                    grid=list(rows=3, columns=2),
                    xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                    yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Is this for R? texttemplate does not appear to exist.

Comment: Sure is this for R. See `https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/#customize-displayed-text-with-a-text-template`. What's the issue with the code? Which version of plotly are you using? Mine is 4.9.2.1.

Comment: I have the same version. So it gives the error: "Warning message:
'pie' objects don't have these attributes: 'texttemplate'
Valid attributes include:" and then all the allowed attributes

Comment: Hm. I don't get this warning. Additionally I just had a look at the pie attributes via `plotly::schema()` which lists `texttemplate` too. But does the code work? After all, it's just a warning. I had a similar issue some time ago, where r-plotly complained about an attribute. But the code still worked.

Comment: The code does not work but I am using add_pie to combine six of these plots into a figure. Not sure if that should matter at all

Comment: @DFM-1124 Don't think that `add_pie` breaks the code. I just tried that. Therefore I can only suggest that you try to make a reproducible example by adding a snippet of your data to your post, best by using `dput`. This way it's easier to check out what's the issue and how it could be solved. Best S.

Comment: Okay, I added a google sheet with an example if the data that I am putting in the chart.

Comment: I just made an edit based on the data you provided. The only change I made was to add `texttemplate = '<b>%{percent}</b>'` (without adding the label) and for the second pie I used the same data as for the first. As you see from the screenshot this gives me bold labels. Hope this works this time. Best S.

Comment: I think the question now is more about why I don't have texttemplate and how do I get it. Also, the data I provided does not have decimals but your plot does. I am having this problem with two of my six plots. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Concerning your second question. My fault. `%{percent}` will give the percentages. I you want the values you have to use `%{value}`. Concerning your first issue I'm afraid I can't help except for the usual things like update your packages, update R, update R Studio ... or you could try your luck on the plotly github page. But if no one is able to reproduce your issue it's hard to figure out what's going wrong. Sorry. Best S.

Comment: Okay, I just updated everything and got it to work! Thank you! One last question: how do I bold the legend? Looking at the layout attributes I thought it would be similar such as applying layoutTemplate = '<b>%{Compounds}</b>', but it did not work

Comment: Great. Just had a look a the docs. Unfortunately I haven't found anything like texttemplate for the legend. But you can do `labels = paste0("<b>", concWDper$Compounds, "</b>")`.